# AWK argument prints unwanted newline

Tags: excel, bash, csv, awk

> **Disclaimer:** I used an extremely simple example thinking each argument had some hidden encoding I wasn't aware of. Turns out my
>   formatting was entirely wrong. As @miken32 said, I should be using
>   commas. I changed my format and it works perfectly. Valuable lesson
>   learned.

I've exported a `csv`file from an `xlsl` with Excel 2013 (on Windows). I emailed myself the new `csv` file and am running these tests on Unix (MacOS Sierra).

Consider the following CSV file:

```
John
Adam
Cameron
Jordan
```

I'm trying to format each line to look like this:

```
{'operator':'EQ', 'property':'first_name', 'value':'John'},
{'operator':'EQ', 'property':'first_name', 'value':'Adam'},
{'operator':'EQ', 'property':'first_name', 'value':'Cameron'},
{'operator':'EQ', 'property':'first_name', 'value':'Jordan'}
```

So `value` is the only argument changing between each line.

Here is the `awk` file I wrote:

```
BEGIN { }
{
    print "{'operator':'EQ', 'property':'first_name', 'value':'"$0"'},";
}
END { }
```

But after executing this is the output I get:

```
{'operator':'EQ', 'property':'first_name', 'value':'John
'},
{'operator':'EQ', 'property':'first_name', 'value':'Adam
'},
```

Notice how right after the argument ($0) is printed out, a newline is printed? This is messing with my JSON format. I have a feeling this has to do with the excel exporting (which was done by `Save as .csv`).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `$1` instead of `$0`? What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: @miken32 What about the case where there are unknown number of first names? `Ricky Bobby`? `Ricky Bobby Jr.`? `Cal Naughton Jr.`?

Comment: If it's a CSV file you should be using a comma as a field delimiter. That's what the C stands for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In awk, `$0` represents the entire line, whereas `$1`, `$2`, `$n` represent the delimited fields in the line.

The sample provided isn't a CSV file, since there aren't any values separated by commas. If it were, you could do this:

```
 awk -F, '{print "{'"'"'operator'"'"':'"'"'EQ'"'"', '"'"'property'"'"':'"'"'first_name'"'"', '"'"'value'"'"':'"'"'"$1"'"'"'},"}' foo.txt
```

Which gets a bit crazy with the shell-friendly quoting!

You should be aware that there are tools such as `jq`, which are designed to create and work with JSON data. If this is more than a one-off task you might be better served looking at those.

Edit using a suggestion by [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) from a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006825/awk-argument-prints-unwanted-newline/43007287#comment73106015_43007287):

```
 awk -F, '{print "{\047operator\047:\047EQ\047, \047property\047:\047first_name\047, \047value\047:\047"$1"\047},"}' foo.txt
```

(But from your original question it looks like you're using a separate script file anyway, so you won't have to worry about escaping quotes.)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll take a look at `jq`.

Comment: You shouldnt write that script. The problem you're fighting is that you can't include a signle quote in a single-quoted delimited script. That's a shell thing and applies no matter what tool is interpreting the script - awk, sed, whatever. The solutions for awk at least are either 1) Store the script in a file and invoke it as `awk -f script input` and then you can use single quotes in it since it's no longer single quote delimited, or 2) Use `\047` everywhere you want a single quote, e.g. `awk -F, '{print "{\047operator\047:\047EQ\047,...`. Not pretty but harder to mistype and more flexible.

Comment: @EdMorton Yeah I realized after I started that it was going to get a bit unwieldy but figured I'd just push on through since it looks like OP is using a separate script file. I was not aware of your second suggestion, which I'll definitely use in the future. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Just remember to always use the octal `\047` and not be tempted by the hex `\x27` you'll see some people suggest. See http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote for why.

Answer (score 1):

As has been noted, your sample output with `'`-based quoting isn't valid JSON, where only `"` may be used.

Ensuring valid JSON output is a good reason to 
use the [`jq` CLI](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), which not only makes the task more robust, but also simplifies it:

```
jq -Rnc 'inputs | { operator: "EQ", property: "first_name", value: . }' <<EOF
John
Adam
Cameron
Jordan
EOF
```

yields:

```
{"operator":"EQ","property":"first_name","value":"John"}    
{"operator":"EQ","property":"first_name","value":"Adam"}
{"operator":"EQ","property":"first_name","value":"Cameron"}
{"operator":"EQ","property":"first_name","value":"Jordan"}
```

Explanation:

- `-R` reads *R*aw input (input that isn't JSON)
- `-n` suppresses automatic reading of the input, so that special variables `input` and `inputs` can be used instead.
- `-c` produces *c*ompact output (not pretty-printed)
- `inputs` represents all input lines, and the expression after `|` sees each line as `.`, iteratively.
- The output object can be specified using JavaScript syntax, which simplifies matters because the property names don't require quoting; the expanded value of `{ ... }` is converted to JSON on output.

Comment: Better solution than mine if you have `jq` installed. It will properly escape values as well.

Comment: @miken32: Thanks. Installing `jq` is well worth it (if possible) - it's a remarkably powerful utility, primarily for JSON processing, but not just.

Answer (score 0):

Perl:

```
perl -MJSON -nlE 'push @p,{operator=>"EQ",property=>"first_name",value=>$_}}{say JSON->new->pretty->encode(\@p)' file
```

output is valid, pretty-printed JSON:

```
[
   {
      "operator" : "EQ",
      "property" : "first_name",
      "value" : "John"
   },
   {
      "operator" : "EQ",
      "value" : "Adam",
      "property" : "first_name"
   },
   {
      "operator" : "EQ",
      "property" : "first_name",
      "value" : "Cameron"
   },
   {
      "property" : "first_name",
      "value" : "Jordan",
      "operator" : "EQ"
   }
]
```

more readble:

```
perl -MJSON -nlE '
        push @p, { operator=>"EQ", property=>"first_name", value=>$_}
        END {
                say JSON->new->pretty->encode(\@p)
        }' file
```

If you generating JSON, a final note: in the `JSON` the single quotes aren't allowed.