# bash script using awk - printing unwanted newline?

Tags: bash, awk

I'm writing a bash script for a class assignment, and I'm getting some very strange behavior from awk. It seems like it's writing two newlines for a single \n character. Here's the part of the code in question:

```
iterate () {
    for (( i=0; i<$2; i++ )); do
        echo -n $(date +%H:%M:%S) >> cpu_usage.plot
        echo -n $(date +%H:%M:%S) >> disk_usage.plot
        mpstat | awk 'NR>3 { printf "\t"$4"\t"$6"\t"$13"\n" }' >> cpu_usage.plot
        iostat | awk 'NR>6 { printf "\t"$3"\t"$4"\n" }' >> disk_usage.plot
        sleep $1
    done
}
```

The output for cpu_usage.plot is fine, but the output for disk_usage.plot is wrong. It's printing one newline too many between each iteration.

Relevant lines from cpu_usage.plot after execution:

```
17:33:28    0.64    0.02    99.33
17:33:30    0.64    0.02    99.33
17:33:32    0.64    0.02    99.33
17:33:34    0.64    0.02    99.33
```

And from disk_usage.plot:

```
17:33:28    2.16    50.90

17:33:30    2.16    50.90

17:33:32    2.16    50.90

17:33:34    2.16    50.90
```

I would normally think this was an issue with it picking up an extra newline from iostat or something, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Changing line 6 to:

```
iostat | awk 'NR>6 { printf "\t"$3"\t"$4 }' >> disk_usage.plot # removing the "\n"
```

doesn't print any newlines at all; the whole thing is on one line. Messing with the conditional for what lines to grab tends to break things further, and with NR>6 it grabs the correct data, anyway.

It's really bizarre to me that both commands are pretty much identical, other than its input and where it sends the output, but one does it correctly and the other does not. A search of StackOverflow yielded [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006825/awk-argument-prints-unwanted-newline), which I thought might be helpful, but they appear to have been having a different issue. I admit that I'm brand new to awk, but I'm totally at a loss here. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You should use `printf` with a format string and arguments `printf "%s\t%s %s\n",  strftime("%H:%M:%S"), $3, $4 `. Reduces the number of quotes and possible errors, and makes the intention more visible. No need to write to the file from different sides, awk is grown up and is able to print timestamps itself. Adds to the 'intention visible', keep the line printing in one place.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to remember that. I figured there was probably a much cleaner way to do it. Separating the format string and arguments probably should've occurred to me, since I've used printf in other languages often enough before. Didn't know about awk's time function, though, and what I did was the only way I could think of to make it print the output of a bash command literally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iostat` outputs one trailing empty line. I suggest:

```
iostat | awk 'NR>6 && $0 != "" { printf "\t"$3"\t"$4"\n" }' >> disk_usage.plot
```

or

```
iostat | awk 'NR>6 && $0 != "" { print "\t"$3"\t"$4 }' >> disk_usage.plot
```

Comment: Okay, that worked, but I'm... still not sure why. Wouldn't

    iostat | awk 'NR>6 { printf "\t"$3"\t"$4 }' >> disk_usage.plot

have done the same thing? It should've still been picking up the extra newline from iostat, resulting in just one newline, right? (Edit: can't get the code line to format correctly. Maybe because it's not a top-level comment?)

Comment: `iostat` outputs one trailing empty line and your awk code copies this empty line with every loop to file `disk_usage.plot`. An empty line has no column 3 and 4.

Comment: Ohhh, so it's printing the full blank line, and not the equivalent of a newline character. That makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to remove `"\n"` replace `printf` by `print`.

Comment: Without the `\n`in your command it prints one line, and the trailing empty line is printed directly behind. The trick in @Cyrus code is the `&& $0 != ""` which skips  empty lines.